# How to check if String like "08-Nov-2011" is a valid date using java?

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if input string is valid date or not.
String be like :-
   `"08-Nov-2011"`
   `"21 Mar 2019"`

java code :-

```
boolean checkFormat;
String input = "08-Nov-2011";
if (input.matches("([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})"))
     checkFormat=true;
else
     checkFormat=false;

 System.out.println(checkFormat);
```

I am thinking of splitting and then check by its length like if first split word be of length 2, second split word be of length 3 and last word be of length 4.

But if Input String be like :-
`AB-000-MN89`
Then here it will fails.

Please help me to Solve this.

Comment: Do you mean to check that the *digits* and *letters* are in the right place and of the right length? Or do you actually want to validate the date?

Comment: I have to validate the dates.

Comment: Don't use a regex. Use a `java.time.DateTimeFormatter` (or multiple ones, if you support more than one) and try to parse the String.

Comment: Try parsing the string and catch possible failures if you support multiple formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with the following pattern: `dd-MMM-yyyy`. Follow the link to see possible patterns.

`SimpleDateFormat` may throw `ParseException` where argument is invalid. So, you can wrap that invocation with a try-catch block.

As an example:

```java
private final String pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
private final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

public boolean validateDate(String date) {
    try {
        sdf.parse(date);
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you have different formats as `08-Nov-2011` and `08 Nov 2011`, try to unify them (by removing dashes from the first one, for instance).

Comment: Note that `SimpleDateFormat` has the habit of ignoring invalid content after a match. The solution would also eliminate the need to catch an exception: `ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0); return sdf.parse(date, pos) != null && pos.getIndex() == date.length();`

Answer (score 3):

As stated in several comments, the best way to find out if your date is valid is to try to parse it with a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` to a date object of type `LocalDate`.
You can support several patterns and/or use built-in ones from the `DateTimeFormatter` class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // provide some patterns to be supported (NOTE: there are also built-in patterns!)
    List<String> supportedPatterns = new ArrayList<>();
    supportedPatterns.add("dd.MMM.yyyy");
    supportedPatterns.add("dd MMM yyyy");
    supportedPatterns.add("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    supportedPatterns.add("dd/MMM/yyyy");
    supportedPatterns.add("ddMMMyyyy");

    // define some test input
    String input = "08-Nov-2011";

    // provide a variable for each, pattern and the date
    String patternThatWorked = null;
    LocalDate output = null;

    // try to parse the input with the supported patterns
    for (String pattern : supportedPatterns) {
        try {
            output = LocalDate.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern));
            // until it worked (the line above this comment did not throw an Exception)
            patternThatWorked = pattern; // store the pattern that "made your day" and exit the loop
            break;
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            // no need for anything here but telling the loop to do the next try
            continue;
        }
    }

    // check if the parsing was successful (output must have a value)
    if (output != null) {
        System.out.println("Successfully parsed " + input 
                + " to " + output.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE) // BUILT-IN pattern!
                + " having used the pattern " + patternThatWorked);
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
Successfully parsed 08-Nov-2011 to 2011-11-08 having used the pattern dd-MMM-yyyy
```

Comment: I think to go with the DateTimeFormatter is the right way, but it's still bugging me to use Exceptions for control flow...

Comment: @dertoni I don't really like that way, too, but in this special case, it is the least troublesome way. A slightly better way would be to catch the `DateTimeParseException` instead of every `Exception`. I will update that here...

Comment: @dertoni you can do without exceptions like `ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0); for(String pattern : supportedPatterns) { if(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern) .toFormat().parseObject(date, pos) != null && pos.getIndex() == date.length()) return true; else pos.setIndex(0); } return false;`

Answer (score 0):

A very crude regex for this would be:

```
\d{2}[- ]\w{3}[- ]\d{4}
08-Nov-2011
21 Mar 2019
```

Example here: https://regex101.com/r/01vslq/1.

However, it would probably be better to get a regex that don't allow dates like `99-Nov-9999`, and so you could try a more thorough one [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html). However, even better, probably using Java date parsing -- this isn't a great use case for regex if you need to do legitimate date parsing -- for example, February shouldn't allow the numbers 29, 30, 31, and lots of other nuances. Use `java.time.DateTimeFormatter` (mentioned in the comment above).